# Linux supported IDE for Ruby on rails development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, ide

what is the best IDE for developing Ruby on rails project for a website on Linux based platform ? i also need to devrlop the front end . i am using mongodb for database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[NetBeans](http://netbeans.org/) is pretty good.

Comment: +1 NetBeans is the best free IDE out there, and when you have a strong computer (free 0.5 GB for an IDE) then it's IMHO beating the editors (non IDE).

Answer (score 3):

Vim with the `rails.vim` and `snipMate` scripts :)

Comment: I found that Ruby is succinct enough to not need snippets. Still Vim rocks!

Answer (score 3):

Personally I just use a Sublime Text Editer that makes most easy for our code development....

Sublime Text is a sophisticated text editor for code, markup and prose.
features

1. slick user interface
2. extraordinary features
3. amazing performance
4. no need to install (Portable)

   more info : [www.sublimetext.com](http://www.sublimetext.com)

Comment: Hey, I installed Sublime and I love it !

Answer (score 2):

Personally I just use a text editor, but I've heard good things from other developers about [RubyMine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RubyMine).

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend Komodo Edit http://www.activestate.com/komodo-edit

I've used it for several Rails projects now. It's a nice text editor with good project browsing and a few convenience features. Works on Mac, Windows and Linux, so is nice and portable.

I tried the pay version, but found it to be overkill.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to go lightweight, vim + rails.vim is an awesome combo.

If you want a heavier IDE, check out [RubyMine](http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/download/index.html#linux). I've been using it for about 5 months now, and it's really quite excellent - I'm not normally an IDE guy, but it's got enough nice features that I've stuck with it.

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/danlucraft/redcar

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you avoid finding some bloated memory hog of an IDE. You don't get much benefit from them in dynamically typed languages. If you want syntax highlighting, indentation, easy project navigation, etc, just use vim with [rails.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1567), as jrdioko suggested. You'll be impressed with many of its features and it's super lightweight.

Answer (score 1):

It's not an IDE, but I really rate using Gedit with the [Gmate plugin](https://github.com/gmate/gmate)

Answer (score 0):

Download Aptana's RadRails -- http://www.aptana.com/products/radrails/download.html

Answer (score 0):

Try out RubyMine 6. It is amazing.
It has pretty good features for specially Ruby on Rails.